# Is this a MWBC?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, neutral, mwbc

I think I have some MWBCs that are not handle tied. Can you tell from this picture if the bottom red breakers and top blue breakers are MWBCs?  I can't trace back to the conduit and they supply "typical" MWBC destinations like kitchen.

[image]

---

Thank you for the helpful comments!! Attaching more pictures (I had an old account apparently).

That zip tie is for the generator interlock

It seems like I might have opened up a can of worms. I wonder why inspector didn't stuff when we moved in. Damn.

So I should be replacing those non-Bryant breakers with an Eaton substitute and getting tied breakers for the MWBCs? Anything else obviously screwed up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us clear shots of the overall panel + the rest of the right side?

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

We can't really tell from this close up of a picture, but your primary remark that they aren't handle tied isn't alarming since the requirement for handle ties is only about 20 years old. Any work older than the requirement change only needs to be brought up to current code when modified.

But while you're there you need to look at the panel cover and see what breakers are (UL) *Listed* for use in that panel. We can see Bryant, GE, and maybe some ITE breakers. I'm not sure what brand of panel you have, but even though those breakers all seem to fit I am not aware of any brand of panel that has been tested by an underwriting lab for using multiple brands of breakers. There are a few breakers that are listed for multiple panels, they bear an obvious [circle logo that says "Classified"](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/catalog/electrical-circuit-protection/classified-circuit-breakers.html). The manufacturers of Classified breakers publish a list which indicates which specific breakers the classified breakers have been tested to replace.

A majority of the breakers in your panel seem to be Bryant, a brand name that Eaton has discontinued, but Eaton brand breakers bearing the same catalog numbers are the *Listed* substitute.

But what the heck is going on with the zip tie around the top pair of breakers?

Comment: Maybe someone was trying to avoid having to use a dual-pole breaker?

Comment: @SteveSh Could be, I guess I should have specified that fixing that should be a top piority. Shimming that breaker out of alignment can only be making a bad situation worse!

Comment: I've seen generator interlock kits which instruct you to wrap a zip-tie (they use some other phrase like "restraining strap" or something similar) around the breaker you're back-feeding over to the breaker pair on the opposite side.

Comment: [This one](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0163JHVYY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) - where it's referred to as a "generator breaker retainer".

Comment: Probably wanted to designate it as a MWBC.  Had something similar in my 1980 installed panel. No handle ties for a refrig and a few kitchen outlets, but a piece of #14 bracketed on the edge of both breakers.  Same thing for a disposal and dishwasher MWBC.

Comment: @brhans Yikes, I guess those installation instructions would make me leery of anything "classified" by Eurofins/Metlabs. I guess what threw me is it looks like the location of the zip tie is binding the wires to the breaker, which if it is to secure the breaker it would somewhat defeat that intent.

Comment: Regarding the zip tied breaker, I have seen this done with gen xfer switches, but in this case I doubt its generator transfer switch because it's in the "on" position. But that doesn't mean I have a clue as to why they are zip-tied!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson If it is the xfer kit linked by brhans the backfeed would be the breaker on the left side of the panel, which we can't quite see if on or off, and would explain the probable need for crowding circuits into the minibreakers below it.

Comment: Also the double terminations on the neutral bus are a no-go. Probably the easiest fix is to add a ground bar. (The part number for the kit is probably on the cover also.)

Comment: @NoSparksPlease  Good point.  I recently installed an interlock on a SquareD QO panel and it was on the upper right. *sigh* too many assumptions I have made!

Comment: @brhans that's to provide breaker lockdown for both backfeed sides.  Very rinkydink; no manufacturer interlock would do that.  Nosparks well,  Eurofins/MetLabs is on the NRTL list, apparently.

Comment: That technique of twisting a bunch of grounds together onto a neutral slot is also no good.  If it ever had a contact problem with the slot, all the grounds would be connected to each other, but not to the neutral/ground.  That means a ground fault in any one of them would **light up all the grounds**.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, I (grudgingly) recognize Eurofins is on the list, but that doesn't automatically make me like them or it. I don't like leaving a job not comfortable with what I've just done to the customer instead of for the customer.

Comment: A few quick observations:  1)  Worried about the rust/corrosion on some of the connections on the breakers. Also looks like a lot of rust at the bottom of the panel.  Was this very wet or flooded at some point? 2)  Individual wires passing thru a cable clamp at the bottom of the panel.   Clearly not cable.  3)  Is it code legal to have a type S cable for the generator directly terminated in the panel?  I presume the other end of it has a plug that connects to the generator. 4)  White wires used as hots not code taped black. 5) grounding bussbar undersized, over-utilized.